# How to edit php matrix use mysql. (Multiple variables)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, matrix

Example:

```
<?php
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",22,18),
array("BMW",15,13),
array("Saab",5,2),
array("Land Rover",17,15)
);

echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[2][0].": In stock: ".$cars[2][1].", sold: ".$cars[2][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[3][0].": In stock: ".$cars[3][1].", sold: ".$cars[3][2].".<br>";
?>
```

And i try my method but didn't worked any idea ? Method:

```
$info = array
(
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        array($row["id"],$row["name"],$row["mname"],$row["sdate"],$row["fdate"],$row["bphoto"],$row["sphoto"],
        $row["text"],$row["one"],$row["two"],$row["three"],$row["four"],$row["five"],$row["six"],$row["seven"],
        $row["eight"],$row["nine"],$row["imdb"],$row["sztrailer"],$row["etrailer"]),
    }
);
```

Query:

```
document.getElementById("alcim").innerHTML = "(" + ' . $info[$_GET["list"]][2] . ' + " " + ' . $info[$_GET["list"]][3] . ' + "-" + ' . $info[$_GET["list"]][4] . ' + ")";
```

Any idea ?
How to edit php matrix values use mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$info = array
(
    while()[...]
```

THAT is wrong. you don't put php-commands inside an array. you only put values inside an array. try this:

```
$info = [];//prettier short-hand version of array()
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $info[] = $row; //append $row, which allready is an array containing all you want, to $info
}
```

THEN you can output your $info with a loop.

Comment: Thank you, and I still use it example --> $info[$row]["id"] = $row["id"]; And this is inside a while loop ?